# How do I write a program where the user enters a integer and it is printed showing asterisks in the form of a triangle

Tags: java

I need to write a program that asks the user to enter the size of a triangle (an integer from 1 to 50). Display the triangle by writing lines of asterisks. The first line
will have one asterisk, the next two, and so on, with each line having one
more asterisk than the previous line, up to the number entered by the user.
On the next line I need one fewer asterisk and continue by decreasing the
number of asterisks by 1 for each successive line until only one asterisk is
displayed. (A hint given was use nested for loops; the outside loop controls the number of lines to write, and the inside loop controls the number of asterisks to display on a line.) For example, if the user enters 3, the output would be

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

Below is what I have written so far:

```
package lab3Package; 
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
//Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

int tri;
for (tri = 1; tri <= 50; tri ++)
{
System.out.println("*");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track I would first check the boundaries of the input and store it in a variable and use that variable as the boundary of your loop.  You would need to use the nextInt() method in the Scanner class.  You can then use another loop which starts at the boundary of the first loop and decrements instead of increments to draw the other part of your triangle.  So just for sudo code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = in.nextInt();
if(input < 1 || input > 50)
return;
else {
for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
System.out.print("*");
}
for(int i = input; i > 0; i--) {
System.out.print("*");
}
}
```

**EDIT:** My implementation won't work actually - don't use println use print inside the loop.  I would have another loop inside that loop to increment the rows.  So one loop to increment the stars and print them with Sys.out.print and another loop which prints a break based on the user input with Sys.out.println.  This sounds like a school project so I'll let you figure that part out ;) but let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
String s = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < number * 2 - 1; i++) {
    s = i < number ? s + "*" : s.substring(1);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```